# Flutter Switching FAB on PageView Pages with animation in Scaffold

Tags: android, user-interface, animation, flutter, floating-action-button

So I've looked several places for how this is supposed to be implemented and I'm sure I'm missing something trivial, but I have a flutter app with a Scaffold who's body is a PageView. I need to have a different FAB for some pages and the way it's currently set up is the floatingActionButton attribute of the scaffold is set to access an array of FloatingActionButtons with the index being the _currentPageIndex (private variable shared by bottomNavBar and _pageController.

This changes the FAB abruptly which is not the desired behavior.

I'm trying to get the FAB to animate (scale out and scale back) in when the page changes like in the [material spec](https://material.io/design/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#behavior):

> Tabbed Screens
>   When tabs are present, the FAB should briefly disappear, then >reappear when the new content moves into place. This expresses >that the FAB is not connected to any particular tab.

I would appreciate any advice on how to go about implementing it simply (I'm pretty sure I'm missing something trivial). The alternative is to manually animate in and out FABs myself by wrapping it in something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using `AnimatedCrossFade` Widget something like this :

```
        class TestingNewWidgetState extends State<TestingNewWidget> {
          int currentIndex = 0;

          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Scaffold(
              floatingActionButton: AnimatedCrossFade(
                crossFadeState: currentIndex == 0
                    ? CrossFadeState.showFirst
                    : CrossFadeState.showSecond,
                duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                firstChild: FloatingActionButton(
                  onPressed: () => null,
                  child: Icon(Icons.arrow_left),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                ),
                secondChild: FloatingActionButton(
                  onPressed: () => null,
                  child: Icon(Icons.arrow_right),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),
              body: PageView(
                onPageChanged: (index) {
                  setState(() {
                    currentIndex = index;
                  });
                },
                children: <Widget>[
                  Scaffold(
                    body: Center(
                      child: Text("page 1"),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Scaffold(
                    body: Center(
                      child: Text("page 2"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
        }
```

**UPDATE**

Remember you can create your own widget, this is an example using a custom `FloatingActionButton`:

```
        class TestingNewWidgetState extends State<TestingNewWidget> {
          int currentIndex = 0;

          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            var customFabButton;
            if (currentIndex == 0) {
              customFabButton = CustomFabButton(
                color: Colors.red,
                onPressed: () => null,
                icon: Icons.alarm,
              );
            } else if (currentIndex == 1) {
              customFabButton = CustomFabButton(
                color: Colors.blue,
                onPressed: () => null,
                icon: Icons.satellite,
              );
            } else {
              customFabButton = CustomFabButton(
                color: Colors.green,
                onPressed: () => null,
                icon: Icons.verified_user,
              );
            }

            return Scaffold(
              floatingActionButton: customFabButton,
              body: PageView(
                onPageChanged: (index) {
                  setState(() {
                    currentIndex = index;
                  });
                },
                children: <Widget>[
                  Scaffold(
                    body: Center(
                      child: Text("page 1"),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Scaffold(
                    body: Center(
                      child: Text("page 2"),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Scaffold(
                    body: Center(
                      child: Text("page 3"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
        }

        class CustomFabButton extends StatelessWidget {
          final IconData icon;
          final Color color;
          final VoidCallback onPressed;

          const CustomFabButton({Key key, this.icon, this.color, this.onPressed})
              : super(key: key);

          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: onPressed,
              child: AnimatedContainer(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  color: color,
                ),
                duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                height: 50.0,
                width: 50.0,
                child: Icon(icon),
              ),
            );
          }
        }
```

Comment: This would be between two FABs, but I have 5 pages, 3 of which have FABs. I could switch out the first and second children based on state to resolve this but I feel like there should also be a simpler solution that works by default. Some property on the outer scaffold that I need to set maybe?