# Stop recursively rendering of a widget due to Provider ( misuse, I guess )

Tags: flutter

## Problem

Recursive rendering of the Widget due to incorrect (probably) use of Provider.

This is the `main.dart` :

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider<NotesProvider>(
        create: (_) => NotesProvider(),
      ),
      ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeProvider>(
        create: (_) => ThemeProvider(),
      ),
    ],
    child: MyApp(),
  ));
}
```

This redirects to `outer_page` which contains two tabs like this :

[image]

It's code goes to like this :

```dart
class OuterPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/OuterPage';
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return OuterPageState();
  }
}

class OuterPageState extends State<OuterPage> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  int _selectedTab = 0;
  final _pageOptions = [
    NoteScreen(),                       // <- Notes Tab
    NotePageScreen(),              // <- 'Another' Tab
  ];

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var noteProvider = Provider.of<NotesProvider>(context, listen: false);
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/53839983
    var customFabButton;
    if (_selectedTab == 0) {
~~~ SNIP ~~~
```

The default tab is the 'Notes' Tab, which works fine.
'Another' tab, is where the issue lies.

```dart
class NotePageScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  NotePageScreen();

  @override
  NotePageScreenState createState() => NotePageScreenState();
}

class NotePageScreenState extends State<NotePageScreen> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  List<Note> noteList;
  int count = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Provider.of<NotesProvider>(context, listen: false).getAllDecryptedNotes();
    return Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        body: Provider.of<NotesProvider>(context, listen:false).decrypted
            ? NotePage()
            : Container(
                child: Center(
                  child: Text("Add a new Note"),
                ),
              ));
  }
}
```

### What's going on here

I am fetching the decrypted notes from the database.
`NoteProvider.dart` :

```dart
class NotesProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  DatabaseHelper _databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper();
  List<Note> _noteList, decryptedNoteList;
  int _count = 0;
  bool _notesDecrypted = false;

  UnmodifiableListView<Note> get allNotes => UnmodifiableListView(_noteList);

  getNotes() async {
    await _databaseHelper.initializeDatabase();
    List<Note> noteList = await _databaseHelper.getNoteList();
    this._noteList = noteList;
    this._count = noteList.length;
    notifyListeners();
  }

UnmodifiableListView<Note> get allDecryptedNotes =>
      UnmodifiableListView(decryptedNoteList);
  getAllDecryptedNotes() async {
    List<Note> decryptedNoteList = [];
    for (var note in this._noteList) {
      decryptedNoteList.add(await decryptNote(note));
    }
    this.decryptedNoteList = decryptedNoteList;
    this._notesDecrypted = true;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  int get count => _count;
  bool get decrypted => _notesDecrypted;
~~~~ SNIP ~~~~
```

#### What's the problem here

So, what happens is the first time there isn't any decrypted data, but when I swtich tabs and come back again to '**Another**' tab, there are the decrypted notes.

#### What I've tried :

If I set `listen` to `True` on **either** of these :

```dart
Provider.of<NotesProvider>(context, listen: false).getAllDecryptedNotes();
Provider.of<NotesProvider>(context, listen: false).decrypted
```

then the page loads in the first attempt but then it goes on rendering recursively.

That's where the error is.

Thanks :)

### Update - Adding Repo

Repo : https://github.com/LuD1161/notes_app/
Branch : reusable_components